How to add an original date of publication to references?
I need to add an original date of publication to some of my references, a translator name and a special mention into brackets : (Original work published in + year). How to do it? This is my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-verbose, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]   {title}{#1\isdot}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{Bion1983,
author = {Bion, Wilfred R.}, 
title = {Réflexion faite}, 
 year = {2005}, 
 origdate={1967},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text here \autocite{Bion1983}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


The field for the translator already exists: translator indeed.
For the date of the original publication, I suggest to modify the notes macro, which your style (ext-verbose) already defines.
\DeclareFieldFormat{mkbibparens}{\bibopenparen#1\bibcloseparen}

\NewBibliographyString{origdate}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
    origdate = {orig\adddotspace publié}}

\renewbibmacro{note}{%
    \iffieldundef{origyear}%
        {}%
        {\setunit{\addspace}
        \printtext[mkbibparens]{%
        \bibstring{origdate}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printfield{origyear}}%
        \newunit}
    \printfield{note}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Bion1983,
        author={Bion, Wilfred R.},
        title={Réflexion faite},
        year={2005},
        origdate={1967},
        translator={Robert, François}}
    \end{filecontents*}

